# Extracting a certain value from a MySQL table with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hey guys I want to extract a certain value from by database's table IF a condition is met.
My table has the following
http://prntscr.com/38hpry

My textbox1.text = eddye, for example and my second textbox will be the place where my URL will be stored

** I don't have a quite exact idea on how to use the select properly

```
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT users1.username, users1.onedrive From users1 WHERE username = @Username"
```

Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, MySQLConnection)

- Sanitizer
          Command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Username", TextBox1.Text))

  ```
     Data Reader:
  ```

  dbCon.Open()

  ```
      DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

      While DR.Read
          textbox2.text = textbox2.text & DR.Item("onedrive")

      End While
  ```

Can you guys help me? I have the basic Idea in mind, but It's incomplete and I am sure my select/parameter_sanitizer is wrong, Thanks

Comment: How do you initialize the SQLCmd?

Comment: Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, MySQLConnection)

Comment: Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection/
 /Dim strQuery As String = ""
   / Dim SQLCmd As MySqlCommand
  /  Dim DR As MySqlDataReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, and the parameterized query seems to be correct, however some other code is missing. You need to open a connection to your database and associate the MySqlCommand to the connection

```
  Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT users1.username, users1.onedrive " & _
                           "From users1 WHERE username = @Username"
  Using con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)
  Using SQLcmd = new MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, con)
      con.Open()
      SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Username", TextBox1.Text))
      Using DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
         While DR.Read
            textbox2.text = textbox2.text & DR.Item("onedrive")
         End While
      End Using
 End Using
 End Using
```

Perhaps you could just change the line that build the parameter with a simple

```
 SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox1.Text)
```

The only real improvement that you could do is the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) that encloses every disposable object used in your code. This statement allows a correct closing and disposing of the connection and the other objects involved (also in case of Exceptions)

Comment: Thank you, it is working. I am really new to this mySQL stuff in VB.net and I am learning slowly. I have tested things around and they're working properly, thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the way you set the value in textBox2. To see al records you need a MultiLine textbox with vertical scrollbar and probably you need to add an Environment.NewLine between every record added

Comment: One newb question, I've seen that you're using : 'Using'
What's the diffrence between:
Using DR = .....
and
DR = ....

Comment: A MySqlDataReader is a disposable object that need to be disposed when you don't need it anymore. End Using takes care of that, The same is true for the MySqlCommand e for the MySqlConnection, This last one is very important because the relative End Using close also the connection